# What even fires when a draggable is dropped on a sortable?

Tags: jquery

In following code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjsfiddlenetuser/zyUkd/)):

```
<div class="connected">
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 01</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 02</div>
    <div class="myDivs excludeThisCss">Hello 03</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 04</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 05</div>
    <div class="myDivs excludeThisCss">Hello 06</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 07</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 08</div>
    <div class="myDivs excludeThisCss">Hello 09</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 10</div>
</div>

<div class="connected">
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 01</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 02</div>
    <div class="myDivs excludeThisCss">Hello 03</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 04</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 05</div>
    <div class="myDivs excludeThisCss">Hello 06</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 07</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 08</div>
    <div class="myDivs excludeThisCss">Hello 09</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 10</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".connected" ).sortable({
        connectWith : ".connected",
        items       : ".myDivs:not(.excludeThisCss)"
    }).disableSelection();

});​
```

CSS:

```
.connected {
    float: left;
    margin: 6px;
}
.myDivs {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 120px;
    background: #F2F2F2;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    color: #1C94C4;
}
.excludeThisCss {
    background: pink;
}
​
​
```

I'm attempting to execute code when an item dragged & dropped. Is there a event that fires when a draggable is dropped on a sortable ?

Comment: In future, please don't *just* include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should standalone from any other resource; consider what'd happen if jsFiddle went down in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the `stop` event :

```
stop: function(event, ui) { ... }
```

[Updated jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/zyUkd/78/) and [docs for the event are here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-stop)

the `ui` object consists of the following :

- `ui.helper` - the current helper element (most often a clone of the item)
- `ui.position` - current position of the helper
- `ui.offset` - current absolute position of the helper
- `ui.item` - the current dragged element
- `ui.placeholder` - the placeholder (if you defined one)
- `ui.sender` - the sortable where the item comes from (only exists if you move from one connected list to another)